# apache event mpm hangs sporadicly

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm running apache Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) using event mpm with php-fpm and occasionally apache will just hang for a few minutes. I will get a notification that the server is down and I will investigate and I don't see anything wrong. Error and Access logs don't show anything out of the norm. Server load is low, plenty of memory left, and if I run apachectl status on the cmd line to see the scorecard that will hang. Eventually it will load after a few minutes with the entire scorecard set to W, and the site will start loading again. This happens about once a day with a new server setup and I have a feeling its something to do with my mpm event configuration. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: It sounds very much like your request are taking longer than normal and then backing up to where you have no free workers.  I'd request and monitor `/server-status` regularly to see if you can catch when it happens. I'd also add "%D" to your `LogFormat` so that you can see the time taken to service requests and see if there is a particular URL or URL type that is taking longer to process than expected at the times this happens

Comment: I've done that and I don't see a particular troubled script.  I've even changed it to worker mpm and I'm still having issues.  It's pathetic, I can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We have been debugging an issue today, that fits your description perfectly. We experienced this issue on Apache 2.4.25 on Debian Stretch.

From reading GDB thread dumps and Googling for suspicious looking symbols, we eventually found this bug report, that seemed to fit the problem:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60956

It seems that the bug was introduced in Apache 2.4.12, and finally fixed in 2.4.28. We backported Apache 2.4.33 from Debian Buster to Stretch. We'll have to monitor the server for a few days to be sure, but we're quite confident that this has fixed it for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel) with Event MPM. It occasionally hangs for one or two minutes, once per day or two days. When it hangs, CPU, memory, TCP connections are normal as usual, but no responding from http, including static contents, even /server-status. A few seconds later, everything is back to normal. No error log.

My server is low, about 50 concurrent connections on static contents, with 16G memory and SSD. So it is definitely not a hardware issue.

There is no cache modules, cgi modules, php/php-fpm contents. But I have mod_proxy and mod_wsgi(daemon), I don't known whether they are related.

Since I've changed it to worker MPM in cPanel, the issue is gone.

Comment: I tired changing it to worker mpm that didn't work for me.